# tags with class in html

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a CSS class which I frequently add to inline HTML elements to change display.

in CSS:

```
  .mymath{ font-family:...; color:...;...}
```

in HTML:

```
normal text <span class="mymath"> math text </span> normal text
```

Is there anything shorter I can use than `<span class="mymath">` ?

Does CSS/javascript help in any way ?

Please mention if solution involves HTML5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not a question at all.

Comment: Not sure what you're actually asking, you have a CSS class with various rules defined for font and colour, and you're applying it....I don't see what the question is?

Comment: What's wrong with specifying a class name? Why do you even care about length?

Comment: You can forgo the class on the span if you have a structure that will allow you to target the spans without affecting other spans via ancestor and descendant selectors.

Comment: No, other than using a shorter class name, or using specific tags for specific styling (but seriously, ***don't***, it's hideously non-semantic), such as an `em` for all orange, underlined text, and `strong` for all bold, green text.

Comment: Your question doesn't not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the B tag is semantically meaningless in HTML5 (look it up), i don't mind "abusing" it for on-screen purely-presentational formatting of existing content:

```
  <style>
    b{ font-weight: normal; font-family:...; color:...;...}
  </style>


  normal text <b> math text </b> normal text
```

this reduces your overhead from

```
  "<span class="mymath"></span>"
```

to

```
  "<b></b>"
```

which is quite a bit shorter.

technically, you can even make up your own tags, and as long as you patch them into your HTML5 shim for IE, the CSS will still "take" on the tags. This just fine when javascript marksup an existing document on-the-fly. Just don't publish such malarkey unless you want the validation mob surrounding your house with pitchforks!

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot really use anything shorter. That's about as succinct as it gets. Sure you can shorten your class name. That would make it shorter :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply styles more globally for your html you can target elements instead.
You can also use the shorter version for setting font size, line height and family. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp

Example:

```
body {
  font: normal 12px/14px Arial, Verdana;
}
```

Notice that there is no . in front of body. This will target the  tag in your html. You could also do this for example on a span tag if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to use descendant or child selectors to specify the style you want, which would reduce the amount of classes you need to specify on your elements.  For instance:

```
<style>
  #test > p > span {
     font-weight: bold;
  }
  #test span {
     color: red;
  }
</style>

<div id="test">
 <p>my content <span>different</span> more content</p>
 <div>
   <p>my content <span>different</span> more content</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

This would make all of the spans text color red, but only the first span bold (untested code there, but you should get the idea).

[Here's a link](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/) to a decent set of tutorials on css selectors you might find helpful.

However, this is really not a good idea.  This means your style is very closely tied to the structure of your document, and so is very fragile.  Adding more classes to your elements gives you a much finer grained degree of control, and is much less fragile - the styling will remain consistent even when the structure of the document changes.

Comment: Also descendant selectors, according to Mozilla, are the most expensive selector you can use.

Comment: Yes, although generally speaking performance of selectors isn't high on the list of performance issues most sites/developers have to deal with today. :) I think the performance of the developer (cost of maintenance) is a much bigger factor in almost all cases.

Comment: I'll certainly agree with that.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, creating a .css file will help. You won't need to have your CSS inline. You just need to add a refernce to your CSS file in each of your html pages.

Comment: He specifically mentions `in CSS: `. So this is redundant, as he's already using a .css file.

Comment: Sorry! misread question as meaning the CSS declaration was inline

Comment: Well the question was/is quite unclear :)